# How do I kill a certain mob outside of a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been working on this project and I need to kill an entity that has left a radius. I used this command but it didn't work.

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,!r=100]
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

The target selector for targets outside a certain radius is `rm=<range>`.  The `m`, like other selector arguments, stands for minimum.

Thus, your command would be `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,rm=100]`.

Comment: this no longer seems to be the case, as the rm selector was removed. is there another solution to this either with the `distance` selector or otherwise?